# ng-model in select box is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using angular js to draw select boxes.

```
 <select ng-model="selected">
     <option value="{{obj.id}}" ng-repeat="obj in values">{{obj.name}} </option>
 </select>
 selected id - {{selected}}
```

Here the default selected is not initialized according to value `selected`.

Have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/1982/) for the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Td2NZ/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive to render selectbox options:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in values"></select>
```

**Fixed demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/1984/

Comment: This still does not work.  The model is not updated in the controller scope.

Comment: @Tyguy7 There is something with your code. Post the question.

Answer (score 2):

case 2 is updated in this plunker

http://jsfiddle.net/26yjn8ru/

```
 <div ng-repeat="arr in itr">
    <select ng-model="arr.id"
      ng-options="value.id  as value.name for value in values">
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you - I had to use case-2 from this answer.  Case-1 seems to possibly break in older verison sof agnular

Answer (score 1):

Just add ng-selected="selected == obj.id" in the option tag

```
<option value="{{obj.id}}" ng-repeat="obj in values" ng-selected="selected == obj.id" > 
{{obj.name}} 
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Way would be like :

```
<select id="select-type-basic" [(ngModel)]="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status_item of status_values">
    {{status_item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Value Should be avoided inside option since that will set the default value of the 'Select field'. Default Selection should be binded with [(ngModel)] and Options should be declared likewise.

```
status : any = "Completed";
status_values: any = ["In Progress", "Completed", "Closed"];
```

Declaration in .ts file